# Fill empty values from a row with the value of next column on the same row on csv file with pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have this type of `DataFrame`

```
name     surname       middle

Frank    Doe           NaN
John     Nan           Wood
Jack     Putt          Nan
Frank    Nan           Joyce
```

I want to move "middle" values on NaN same rows values on "surname" column. How can i do this? I tried to use the [fillna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna) method but got no results.
Here is my code:

```
import os
from pandas.io.parsers import read_csv


for csvFilename in os.listdir('.'):
   if not csvFilename.endswith('.csv'):
      continue
data=read_csv(csvFilename)
filtered_data["surname"].fillna(filtered_data["middle"].mean(),inplace=True)
filtered_data.to_csv('output.csv' , index=False)
```

Comment: The whitespace in your code does not make sense?  Python requires whitespace for defining levels of nested code. please fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Conditional column flipping

Using [`pd.isnull()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html), columns can be rearranged conditionally.

```py
import pandas as pd
from cStringIO import StringIO

# Create fake DataFrame... you can read this in however you like
df = pd.read_table(StringIO('''
name     surname       middle
Frank    Doe           NaN
John     NaN           Wood
Jack     Putt          NaN
Frank    NaN           Joyce'''), sep='\s+')

print 'Original DataFrame:'
print df
print

# Assign the middle name to any surname with a NaN
df.loc[pd.isnull(df['surname']), 'surname'] = df[pd.isnull(df['surname'])]['middle']

print 'Manipulated DataFrame:'
print df
print
```

---

```
Original DataFrame:
    name surname middle
0  Frank     Doe    NaN
1   John     NaN   Wood
2   Jack    Putt    NaN
3  Frank     NaN  Joyce

Manipulated DataFrame:
    name surname middle
0  Frank     Doe    NaN
1   John    Wood   Wood
2   Jack    Putt    NaN
3  Frank   Joyce  Joyce
```

Comment: sorry but i've to create a fake DataFrame always insert all data of old dataframe?

Comment: The fake `DataFrame` is just for example, you would use your `data` from when you read from the `csv` file.

Comment: You can overwrite `data` like I overwrote `df` with `df.loc[...] = ...`

Comment: yes but if i do this:
data.loc[data.isnull(data['surname']),'surname'] = data[data.isnull(data['surname'])]['middle'] 
i've naturally an error

Comment: you need `pd.isnull()` **not** `data.isnull()`

Comment: Also try to use code formatting with backticks (`\`code\``) in comments. It really make it easier to read.

Comment: I'm sorry, `pd` is a common shortcut for `pandas`. See updated code.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an easier way to do that:

```
df['surname'] = df['middle'].combine_first(df['surname'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    name surname middle
0  Frank     Doe    NaN
1   John    Wood   Wood
2   Jack    Putt    NaN
3  Frank   Joyce  Joyce
```